# Does Aurelia-Fetch have a dependency on whatwg-fetch?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, aurelia, fetch-api

I am trying to upgrade my Aurelia project from a beta version to the March version.

One of the errors I am getting is:

> Cannot find name 'Request'.

Googling this brings up this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/issues/65

This issue says that the "fix" is to install the typescript definitions for `whatwg-fetch`.  When I do install those typescript definitions, the error goes away.

**But does that mean I need `whatwg-fetch` too?**  (Looking in my node_modules folder, `whatwg-fetch` is not installed.)

Comment: You don't need to use `whatwg-fetch` if your target environment supports the fetch API natively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aurelia-fetch-client` wraps the Fetch *API*. `wahtwg-fetch` is a Fetch *polyfill*, so it wouldn't make sense for the fetch client to depend on the polyfill. Furthermore, which polyfill you will use changed depending on which module loader you are using.

JSPM/SystemJS based apps use the fetch polyfill from GitHub, while most other module loaders use `whatwg-fetch`.

So yes, you will need to install `whatwg-fetch`, but there's a good reason for why the `aurelia-fetch-client` doesn't have a dependency on it.

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear about this answer.  Is this saying we need GitHub `fetch` if we're using SystemJS, otherwise we need `whatwg-fetch`?

Comment: As far as I'm currently aware, yes.